# Storing parts of API data to database

Tags: php, database, laravel, rest, guzzle

**Goal:** I want to retrieve all the upcoming soccer matches for the upcoming week from a RESTful API. Once I get this data I would like to store the result in my database.

What I want to store: `'id', 'homeTeam', 'awayTeam', 'utcDate'`. I want to do this for every match, so all the arrays in `'matches'`

How my API result looks:

```
array:4 [▼
"count" => 10
"filters" => array:1 [▶]
"competition" => array:6 [▶]
"matches" => array:10 [▼
0 => array:12 [▼
  "id" => 233107
  "season" => array:4 [▶]
  "utcDate" => "2018-10-20T11:30:00Z"
  "status" => "SCHEDULED"
  "matchday" => 9
  "stage" => "REGULAR_SEASON"
  "group" => "Regular Season"
  "lastUpdated" => "2018-10-07T19:02:21Z"
  "homeTeam" => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 61
    "name" => "Chelsea FC"
  ]
  "awayTeam" => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 66
    "name" => "Manchester United FC"
  ]
  "score" => array:6 [▶]
  "referees" => []
]
1 => array:12 [▶]
2 => array:12 [▶]
3 => array:12 [▶]
4 => array:12 [▶]
5 => array:12 [▶]
6 => array:12 [▶]
7 => array:12 [▶]
8 => array:12 [▶]
9 => array:12 [▶]
 ]
]
```

I use Guzzle for doing this API request:

```
class GuzzleController extends Controller {
    public function getMatches() {
        $client = new Client();
        $uri = 'http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/PL/matches/?matchday=9&season=2018&matches';
        $header = ['headers' => ['X-Auth-Token' => 'My-Token']];
        $res = $client->get($uri, $header);
        $array = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        dd($array);
    }
}
```

I created a model 'Match' and added a migration:

```
class Match extends Model {
    // What code here?
}
```

The migration:

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('matches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('match_id');
        $table->string('homeTeam');
        $table->string('awayTeam');
    });
}
```

Any tips on how to store this data to my database on the match model?

Comment: As a start point, you probably want a model called teams? So that in your match model, you will have match->hasMany teams, or has one homeTeam through teams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by getting all **matches** data and then looping through each one using a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections).

Collections can be created from array data using the [collect()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-collect) helper.

```
class GuzzleController extends Controller
{
    public function getMatches()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $uri = 'http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/PL/matches/?matchday=9&season=2018&matches';
        $header = ['headers' => ['X-Auth-Token' => 'My-Token']];
        $res = $client->get($uri, $header);
        $data = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        return $data['matches'];
    }

    public function saveMatches()
    {
        $matches = $this->getMatches();

        collect($matches)
            ->each(function ($match, $key) {
                Match::create([
                    'match_id' => $match['id'],
                    'homeTeam' => $match['homeTeam']['name'],
                    'awayTeam' => $match['awayTeam']['name']
                ]);
            });
    }
}
```

With this code, we call the `saveMatches()` function, which calls the `getMatches()` function (used to run the guzzle call).

Then, for each match, we save a new record to the database use the `Match` facade.

**Notes**

- As mentioned above, it may be best to create a `Team` model, so you are able to identify and call matches based on teams.
- Make sure to call the `$fillable` or `$guarded` class variable in your `Match` model to be able to store data ([see here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment)).

## Update

To use this functionality in a job, you first need to create a job using

```
php artisan make:job <job name>
```

For example, the job could be called `CreateMatches`. This will be located in `app/Jobs/CreateMatches.php`.

There you will see a `handle()` function, which is used to call any functionality within it once the job has fired.

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->saveMatches();
}

public function saveMatches()
{
    // Code goes here
}

public function getMatches()
{
    // Code goes here
}
```

You can then call the job, anywhere in your application logic using either `CreateMatches::dispatch()`  or by using `dispatch(new CreateMatches())` (don't forget to `use` the class at the top of your file).

Comment: Where is the best place to put these functions in my project? Doing this in the controller will return the full api call in the browser view, (`return json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);`) I want to do this in the background, and load a view based on the database results.

Comment: @Dax You can set this up as a command which is run in the background. As a `job` or as an `event`. I would go for a `job`, do you want me to update the answer?

Comment: That would be very helpful

Comment: Updated, the examples have been shortened. So you can use the code I added earlier in the answer.

Comment: I don't think the collect() helper is working properly, I added the functions to my job and when I run it Laravel throws me this error: `QLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'homeTeam' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `matches` (`homeTeam`, `awayTeam`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) `values (, , 2018-10-18 10:53:25, 2018-10-18 10:53:25)) ` , There are no values for the fields

Comment: Can you `dd()` what `$this->getMatches()` returns

Comment: Or you may need to add to collection in an array e.g `collect([$matches])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182083/discussion-between-dax-and-thisiskelvin).